# What is "u0080-" and "u024F" in Jquery Validation Regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, unicode

I wanted to create a validation for City Names so I picked a Regex code from Google which allow user to accepts only letters and some characters, and to make sure for city names it should accept only "Letters" and "space" b/w two words.

This was the code which I found initially

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cityvalidation", function (value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
}, "You Have Typed Unallowed Charactors");
```

And this is the code which I modified for my city names validation:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cityvalidation", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\s\)\(]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
}, "Please provide a valid city name!");
```

I removed whatever I thought should not be accepted like: **"/-\`.\"\'\"** but I was not sure what does "" means? I searched the Unicodes and found about "u024F" = **Ɏ**, so removed that too but don't know about "**u0080**" still.

Also I noticed in many Regex both these unicode are given as input option.

Can somebody please guide what this means and why these are used in almost all Regex code?

Comment: [Unicode Character '<control>' (U+0080)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/80/index.htm)

Comment: the letters are likely placeholders.

Comment: They were placeholders. The previous comment contained incorrect information, however, so I removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u0080-\u024F` within `[...]` (which is called a "character class") means all characters from `\u0080` to `\u024F` (inclusive). (Another example of "character class": `[a-f]` meaning `a` through `f` inclusive.) The form `\uXXXX` is a Unicode escape using the code `XXXX`. You can look up what the characters are on the [Unicode site](http://unicode.org), which has a page for each character (e.g., [`U+0080`](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0080) and [`U+024F`](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=024F)).